# How to calculate end date of subscription of many users without loading them all each day?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

This is my use case:

- users subscribe for a pass. It can be day, weelk or a month pass.
- when the end of the pass is reached, i want to set the status of the pass to inactive and send sms to my users.

> ```
> private String id;
> private String name;  
> private String description;
> private int nbBook;
> private int nbGame;
> private BigDecimal price; 
> private Boolean status = true;
> private Currency currency;    
> private PassValitidyPeriod validityTime;
> ```

I'm looking for a modern and intelligent way to check when a pass reached the end of subscription.

**WAY 1**
I can use `@Scheduled()` each day, to start a method in which i can get all the users and check the pass status.
cons: When i reach million of users, this can become dangerous for the system. We are going to loads all users, just to check the end date.

Please, is it possible to have directly in the database a trigger calling the java code when the end date is reached ? Or a kind of trigger ? Or what is a good way to do it instead of loading all users each day to check ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would run a periodic task to check for expirations between now and the last checked time. Run it once (or twice) an hour. Why make it more complicated than that?

Comment: We know little about your code, or your database tables. Without that, we can only guess. The quality of such guesses can range from useful to totally useless and way off-base.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, it's not about code. I can get all of my users in Page easily, but is a best way to do ? It's more about how to design this correctly. if you have 10 millions of users, are you going to loads them all to check each day ?

Comment: The point is, we have far too little to go on. As it stands, the question might be out of bounds for Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Could you use an indexed file? The file can have IDs and pass expiration times. If pass expiration times are indexed, the file can be read as if pass expiration times were kept in sorted order.

Comment: Perhaps a persistent version of a [hierarchical timing wheel](https://blog.acolyer.org/2015/11/23/hashed-and-hierarchical-timing-wheels/) is what you need ([link with visuals](https://www.slideshare.net/supperniu/timing-wheels)).

Comment: If the expiration date is registered in the database, build a non-unique index on that column and every day retrieve the passes that expire on the day only.

Comment: @OleV.V. i'm going to try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i use aws Dynamodb database and activate TTL (Time to live).
When I create a new subscription, I add also the end date of the suscription.
Dynamodb deletes when this date is reached...
I added a trigger to detect when the row is deleted and then from a lambda I send the message.

This is fully scalable, and I don't have to iterate each day over all data in database.